# Get POST data in Coldfusion, not in Form

Tags: curl, post, coldfusion

I need to send data in POST to Coldfusion and retrieve them.
The call will be:

```
curl -X POST http://apitest.localhost/test.cfm -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"test": 1}'
```

But inside the test.cfm I can't get the data sent by -d.
I can get the POST data only if they are sent inside a form, like

```
 -F 'form={"test":"1"}'
```

In this case I can access my json data inside a form object.

It's not what I want!!!
Where are the regular body post data?

Answer (score 5):

Oh I found

```
getHttpRequestData().content
```

It seems to work